# Add,delete or update a Object with children entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp-classic

I have a parent model which contains a collection of child, ok now this child has an collection of childofchild, it is a complex model.
I want to add, update or delete Child or ChildOfChild entities if my of my Parent model, since EF 5 there are many changes or new methodes I already searched in the net and found nothing that could solve me this.

Is there a good methode now in EF 7,lineQ  or with a extended libary to update this in a easy or clean way. 
My bad solution would be a foreach with multiple checkings...

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ChildOfChild> Children { get; set; }


    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class ChildOfChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP. Can you remove the tag and replace it with ASP.NET, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are redundant, it enough to use only one model:

**Model:**

```
public class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public virtual Entity Parent { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Code sample:**

```
var dc = new DataContext();
var parent = dc.Entitys.Add(new Entity { Data = "Parent" });
dc.SaveChanges();

dc.Entitys.Add(new Entity { Data = "Child1", ParentID = parent.ID });
dc.Entitys.Add(new Entity { Data = "Child1", ParentID = parent.ID });
var child = dc.Entitys.Add(new Entity { Data = "Child1", ParentID = parent.ID });
dc.SaveChanges();

dc.Entitys.Add(new Entity { Data = "Child2", ParentID = child.ID });
dc.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: And my answer will not be changed. Look, all of your models are the **same**. And at my example I demonstrate how to create chain of items: first - parent, than child and then grandchild, it is logical sequence, not only from point of view programming. What you exactly want, can you show sample, maybe piece of pseudocode?